# Save the result of multiple AKSequencer instances to disk

Tags: ios, audiokit

I am using `AudioKit` to allow the user to select multiple combinations of MIDI and WAV files. For each combination the user chooses I play the MIDI along with the WAV using an `AKSequencer`and `AKMIDISampler` for each pair of files.

The result is all tracks playing together the way I want it.

The thing is I want to save that mix as a file.

I have tried using `AKOfflineRenderNode` but I only get the first note and after that it just beeps until the end of the specified duration.

Here is a sample code of what I have so far:

```
func saveMixToDisk() {
    do {
        AudioKit.output = offlineRender

        for track in tracks {
            let trackSampler = AKMIDISampler()
            try trackSampler.loadWav(track.instrument.fileName)
            trackSampler.connect(to: mixer)

            let sequencer = AKSequencer(filename: track.midi.fileName)
            sequencer.setTempo(Double(tempo))
            sequencer.setRate(rate)
            sequencer.setGlobalMIDIOutput(trackSampler.midiIn)
            sequencer.enableLooping()
            offlineSequencers.append(sequencer)

            trackSampler >>> offlineRender
        }

        AudioKit.start()

        let docs = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        let destinationAudioFile = docs.appendingPathComponent("\(UUID().uuidString).m4a")

        offlineRender.internalRenderEnabled = false
        for sequencer in offlineSequencers {
            sequencer.play()
        }

        try offlineRender.renderToURL(destinationAudioFile, seconds: offlineSequencers.first!.length.seconds)
        for sequencer in offlineSequencers {
            sequencer.stop()
        }
        offlineRender.internalRenderEnabled = true
    } catch let error {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Any help is very appreciated!

Thanks